# Is propagation delay in coax cable a function of signal frequency?

Tags: datasheet, transmission-line, coax

For [this](https://datasheet.octopart.com/8241-010100-Belden-datasheet-7086339.pdf) coax cable, the propagation delay is given as a single parameter in 1.54 ns/ft as follows:

[image]

But isn't the propagation delay function of signal frequency?

Comment: You can say that the "velocity factor" and "propagation delay" given in a coax datasheet are only a first-order approximation. It assumes the cable is an ideal lossless dispersionless transmission line. It's often measured by applying a digital pulse (which is a wideband signal) and testing its end-to-end delay. For many practical purposes when dispersion is negligible, it's good enough. Note that the parameter is called *Nominal* Delay, the word "nominal" already implies it's only a typical value that may change depending on various factors.

Answer (score 8):

Propagation velocity in an ideal transmission line, i.e. one which satisfies "The Telegrapher's" (i.e Heaviside's) equation(s), is frequency dependant (unless LG = RC). This posed significant problems for the first transatlantic telegraph cable, and for early long distance phone systems.

Although the propagation velocity is frequency dependant in an ideal transmission line, there exists, for every such ideal transmission line a frequency above which propagation velocity becomes relatively constant.

For twisted pair transmission lines, this frequency is generally somewhere between 50 kHz and 500 kHz. Coax cables have a similar "break frequency" below which their behavior is significantly frequency dependant.

Then, for real transmission lines, at some point the transmission line parameters start to change significantly, and the real transmission line at very high frequencies will have non-ideal behavior.

If I have done my math correctly, the dispersion relationship for a transmission line which satisfies The Telegrapher's Equation(s) with fixed parameters L, C, R, G is

$$\omega^2 = \frac{k^2 (k^2 + RG)}{k^2LC + \frac{1}{4}(RC+GL)^2}$$

where, as usual, \$\omega\$ is the angular frequency and \$k\$ is the wave number.

Note that there are two distinct velocities that commonly of interest. Phase velocity, and group velocity. Phase velocity tells us how different the phases of a sine wave are at different points along the transmission line. Group velocity tells us how fast the envelope of a signal moves down the transmission line.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally no, it does not. In reality, yes it does because the electrical properties (resistance, capacitance, etc) do vary with frequency.  However, that is an inexpensive coax cable.  The highest frequency speced is 1 GHz, so for its intended purpose the dispersion is negligible and you can assume a constant group velocity.

Comment: This is incorrect. The frequency dependance of the propagation "constant" is a natural feature of a transmission line, even an "ideal" transmission line. Changes in the inductance, capacitance, or resistance with frequency are not a requirement for changes in the propagation "constant" with frequency. It just happens to be the case that the cable in question is expected to be used at a frequency where the propagation "constant" is in fact relatively constant.

Comment: I think the answer is correct in the sense that in my early emag classes we assumed perfect conductors and perfect dielectrics and neglected skin effect. When we talk about an "ideal transmission line" we are referring to a lossless, non-dispersive, perfect group delay piece of utopia. But when we build a t-line to 50GHz we know Er drops with frequency, losses increase, ferromagnetic effects loom large, etc.

Comment: Even so, it is not that the LCGR parameters need to _change_, to introduce frequency dependance. One merely needs to assume that that \$LG \ne RC\$.

Answer (score 0):

Something as this would help ... Maple sheet.
Theoretical line impedance = \$ sqrt(L/C) \$ = 79.94 Ohm for ff >= 6 (1 MHz).

[image]

[image]

This last picture is "phase velocity".

Comment: What does each axis on the graphs represent?

Comment: Log frequency for x-axis, Ohm for the first, speed in m/s for the last.